# Calculate relative frequency of bigrams in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to count word pairs in a text file. First, I've done some pre-processing on the text, and then I counted word pairs as shown below:

`((Aspire, to), 1) ; ((to, inspire), 4) ; ((inspire, before), 38)...`

Now, I want to report the 1000 most frequent pairs, sorted by :

1. Word (second word of the pair)
2. Relative frequency (pair occurences / 2nd word total occurences)

Here's what I've done so far

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import re

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Bigram occurences and relative frequencies").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
text = sc.textFile("big.txt")

tokens = text.map(lambda x: x.lower()).map(lambda x: re.split("[\s,.;:!?]+", x))
pairs = tokens.flatMap(lambda xs: (tuple(x) for x in zip(xs, xs[1:]))).map(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
frame = pairs.toDF(['pair', 'count'])

# Dataframe ordered by the most frequent pair to the least
most_frequent = frame.sort(frame['count'].desc())
# For each row, trying to add a column with the relative frequency, but I'm getting an error
with_rf = frame.withColumn("rf", frame['count'] / (frame.pair._2.sum()))
```

I think I'm relatively close to the result I want but I can't figure it out. I'm new to Spark and DataFrames in general.
I also tried

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
frame.groupBy(frame['pair._2']).agg((F.col('count') / F.sum('count')).alias('rf')).show()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT: here's a sample of the `frame` dataframe**

```
+--------------------+-----+
|                pair|count|
+--------------------+-----+
|{project, gutenberg}|   69|
|  {gutenberg, ebook}|   14|
|         {ebook, of}|    5|
|    {adventures, of}|    6|
|           {by, sir}|   12|
|     {conan, doyle)}|    1|
|     {changing, all}|    2|
|         {all, over}|   24|
+--------------------+-----+

root
 |-- pair: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- count: long (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Can you post a sample data contained in `frame` dataframe and also the schema? and include an output for this sample.

Comment: @Nithish Sorry, I forgot about that. I edited my post.

Comment: By ordering by "Word (second word of the pair)", do you mean alphabetical order or frequency order?

Comment: @Crow59 By alphabetical order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `relative frequency` can be computed by using [`window`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.window.html?highlight=window#pyspark.sql.functions.window) function, that partitions by the second word in the `pair` and applies a [`sum`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.sum.html?highlight=sum#pyspark.sql.functions.sum) operation.

Then, we limit the entries in the df to the top x, based on `count` and finally order by the second word in pair and the relative frequency.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

data = [(("project", "gutenberg"), 69,),
        (("gutenberg", "ebook"), 14,),
        (("ebook", "of"), 5,),
        (("adventures", "of"), 6,),
        (("by", "sir"), 12,),
        (("conan", "doyle"), 1,),
        (("changing", "all"), 2,),
        (("all", "over"), 24,), ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("pair", "count", ))

ws = W.partitionBy(F.col("pair")._2).rowsBetween(W.unboundedPreceding, W.unboundedFollowing)

(df.withColumn("relative_freq", F.col("count") / F.sum("count").over(ws))
   .orderBy(F.col("count").desc())
   .limit(3) # change here to select top 1000
   .orderBy(F.desc(F.col("pair")._2), F.col("relative_freq").desc())
).show()

"""
+--------------------+-----+-------------+
|                pair|count|relative_freq|
+--------------------+-----+-------------+
|         {all, over}|   24|          1.0|
|{project, gutenberg}|   69|          1.0|
|  {gutenberg, ebook}|   14|          1.0|
+--------------------+-----+-------------+
"""
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Shouldn't the relative frequency be equal to 1 in this case? The pair (all, over) occurs 24 times, so the term "over" should occur at least 24 times in the whole dataset, therefore making it 24/24 = 1?

Comment: @cdaveau yes indeed, I mistook it as count of occurences instead of total occures, modified the answer now.

Comment: Thank you very much! That works. If I understand correctly, if I want to order by the 2nd term total occurences, I can just re use the window like this ```orderBy(F.sum("count").over(ws))```?

Comment: @cdaveau yes ordering by the `sum` over window will work.

Comment: Apparently you can't order by the sum over window because the sort operator doesn't support window expressions. Is there any other way than creating another column with 2nd term occurences, then ordering by this column? @Nithish

Comment: @cdaveau Unfotunately not, but since `F.sum("count").over(ws)` is computed anyway for `relative_freq` calculation adding another column to hold this data and use it in orderBy would not have a performance impact.